# How to create dynamic string on Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have the following workflow:

1. Get number from MySqlOperator (dynamic)
2. Get value stored in Variable  (static)
3. Create a string based on both.
4. Use the string as sql command for `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`.

Now, it is proven to be difficult.

This is my code:

```
VALUE_FROM_VARIABLE = Variable.get("my_var")

query = 'SELECT ... FROM orders where orders_id>{0}
          and orderid<{1};'.format(VALUE_FROM_MySqlOperator, VALUE_FROM_VARIABLE)


file_name   = ...
import_orders_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_orders_and_upload_to_storage',
    mysql_conn_id='mysql_con',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_con',
    sql=query,
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    filename=file_name,
    dag=dag)
```

My problem here is that I can't access the `MySqlOperator` XCOM which store the number in need for the query.

So I tried to access it in `PythonOperator` and build the query string as follows:

```
def func(ds, **kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    VALUE_FROM_MySqlOperator = str(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='mySQL_task'))  # get the XCOM of MySqlOperator
    query = 'SELECT ... FROM orders where orders_id>{0}
              and orderid<{1};'.format(VALUE_FROM_MySqlOperator, VALUE_FROM_VARIABLE)
   return query


py_op = PythonOperator(
    task_id='py_op_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=func,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)
```

But now I can't pass the new generated query to the `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` because I can't read the XCOM inside this operator.

How can I get out of this ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL operators are intending to execute queries which are not returning any values. You can use such operators(for example) to move data from stage table to production.

In my opinion, try to avoid creating workflows which are using XCOMS.

If you need to query data from database you can use [Hooks](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=hook#hooks) and [Connections](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#connections)

Untested code is below

```py
VALUE_FROM_VARIABLE = Variable.get("my_var")
query_to_retrieve = "SELECT item FROM table"
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
#here we importing hook, using connection and get first row
VALUE_FROM_MySQL = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='mysql_default').get_first(query_to_retrieve)[0]

query = 'SELECT ... FROM orders where orders_id>{0}
      and orderid<{1};'.format(VALUE_FROM_MySQL, VALUE_FROM_VARIABLE)
```